# Google Fonts (Lato) not rendering on Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, sass

When I load the website in Google Chrome, texts using Lato font are NOT displayed randomly (in modals, or navigation header links). After I hover the styled link, or retrigger any CSS property in Inspector - texts become visible.

I have tried different solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome), but didn't work for me.

I'm loading the fonts **locally**. Here is my font scss:

```
// Lato
//
// The Lato font in a Sass format to be imported easily in any 
// project.
// sass-lint:disable no-duplicate-properties

$fontface-src: '../assets/fonts' !default;

// Regular
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: 
        url($fontface-src + '/lato/Lato-Regular.svg') 
format('svg'),
        url($fontface-src + '/lato/Lato-Regular.ttf') 
format('truetype'),
        url($fontface-src + '/lato/Lato-Regular.woff') 
format('woff'),
        url($fontface-src + '/lato/Lato-Regular.eot'),
        url($fontface-src + '/lato/Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') 
format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

// Light
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src:
        url($fontface-src + '/lato/Lato-Light.svg') format('svg'),
        url($fontface-src + '/lato/Lato-Light.ttf') 
format('truetype'),
        url($fontface-src + '/lato/Lato-Light.woff') 
format('woff'),
        url($fontface-src + '/lato/Lato-Light.eot'),
        url($fontface-src + '/lato/Lato-Light.eot?#iefix') 
format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: can you send an example?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that it has to do with the order of the different font files. A browser picks the first file format it supports and SVG is pretty old school so you may end up with this strange behavior.

Check this answer: [What's the correct order to load fonts in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840115/whats-the-correct-order-to-load-fonts-in)

> Paul Irish suggests that the 'bullet proof' way to load fonts is to
>   render EOT first, followed by WOFF, TTF, and lastly SVG.